# "Incomplete Signature" "The request signature does not conform to platform standards" in Lazada API

Tags: api, e-commerce

I working in connecting our system in Lazada and need to retrieve items. this is my code.

```
    $region = "https://api.lazada.com.ph/rest";
    $getproductitem = "/products/get";
    $app_key = 110150;
    $date = new DateTime();
    $timestamp = 1656029861000;
    $access_token = "token***";
    $app_secret = "secret***";
    $sign_method="sha256";
    $base_str = $getproductitem.'access_token'.$access_token.'app_key'.$app_key.'sign_method'.$sign_method.'timestamp'.$timestamp; 
    $sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_str, $app_secret, false);
    //$sign = hex(sha256($getproductitem.'access_token'.$access_token.'app_key'.$app_key.'sign_method'.$sign_method.'timestamp'.$timestamp));

    //return $uri = "https://api.lazada.com.ph/rest/products/get?app_key=$app_key&access_token=$access_token&sign_method=$sign_method&timestamp=$timestamp&sign=$sign";
    
    $response = Http::get($region.$getproductitem,  [
        "app_key" => $app_key,
        "access_token" => $access_token,
        "sign_method" => $sign_method,
        "timestamp" =>  $timestamp,
        "sign" => $sign,
     ]); 

     return $response->json();
```

but the return is this.

{
"type": "ISV",
"code": "IncompleteSignature",
"message": "The request signature does not conform to platform standards",
"request_id": "212a721616560299294283218"
}

I follow the instruction according to their documentation about setting of sign still i got error. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

make your signature in uppercase

```
$sign = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $base_str, $app_secret));
```

this is the code in the SDK in generating signature

```
protected function generateSign($apiName,$params)
{
    ksort($params);

    $stringToBeSigned = '';
    $stringToBeSigned .= $apiName;
    foreach ($params as $k => $v)
    {
        $stringToBeSigned .= "$k$v";
    }
    unset($k, $v);

    return strtoupper($this->hmac_sha256($stringToBeSigned,$this->secretKey));
}


function hmac_sha256($data, $key){
    return hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key);
}
```

documentation sample is also all in upper case
https://open.lazada.com/doc/doc.htm?spm=a2o9m.11193531.0.0.622b6bbeRPVsjG#?docId=108069&nodeId=10451